# Visio Services "Refresh Disabled" warning message

Tags: visio-services

I have a Visio Web access web part which is pointing to a visio web diagram in my document library. Every time I save my visio web diagram, the user receives the message:

"**Refresh Disabled**   -  Enable refresh if you trust the contents of this file"

(sorry, can't post image as I don't have enough rep points)
There are two buttons within the message -

1. Enable (this session)
2. Enable (always)

Even if 'always' is click, subsequent saves of the web diagram will bring up the message again.
How to I stop this message from appearing after modifying the web drawing?

My visio access web part has a value of 1 minute in the "automatically refresh interval", but I have tried other values too, like zero. My data source is just a sharepoint list within the same site collection. I tried to add a trusted data provider, and an application ID (via the Secure Store Service) but these made no difference. I've also tried to update some of the Visio settings in the Office Customisation Tool (and run the wsp) but this made no difference either, since it is rendering in the browser.

I'm not sure where my answer lies, but I find it hard to believe there isn't a way around this. The user should not have to see this message.

Any help would *really* be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Chris Hopkins' blog post here, it should answer your question:)  His blog is a great one to follow!

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chhopkin/archive/2010/09/28/force-data-refresh-for-published-diagrams.aspx

Comment: Jessica - you have made my week! Thanks a mil. I'd seen this guy's blog before. He is quite the Visio guru. I'd up vote ya if I had the rep points!

Comment: While  this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer inclusion of the  essential parts of the answer here, and to provide the link for  reference. See [answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a configuration problem in the CA  http://sharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-help/blog/2010/10/visio-services-wont-refresh-in-sharepoint-2010how-to-fix-it/